# How to access a function defined in a Typescript/ES6 class? (and how to discern private from public methods)

Tags: typescript

In my application (using Typescript) I have a few functions exported by:

**utility.ts**

```
// I want this function not being accessible elsewhere in the app
function __fn3(){
     console.log('fn2');
}

// I want the following functions to be aprt of a class/interface (see below)
export function fun1 () { console.log('fn1'); }
export function fun2 () { __fn3() }
// etc.
```

in **other-file.ts** I access them by:

```
 import {fun1, fun2} from "/utility";
```

However I would like to define the functions **within a class** "Utility", e.g.

**utility.ts**

```
 export class Utility {
   fun1 () { console.log('fn1'); }
   fun2 () { console.log('fn2'); } }
```

and being able to access them in **other-file.ts** by

> Utility => fun1

(or something like that).

I tried to do the exact same thing, I don't get any error but the function is not execute either. What's wrong in my approach? Perhaps should I define a **module** (if yes, how?) ?

Also, how do I make sure __fn3 is **private** to the class and **not accessible** from elsewhere in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it works just fine. You just have to change the import statement in in **other-file.ts** to import the Utility class instead of the functions.

```js
import {Utiliy} from "/utility";

new Utility().fun1();
```

If you don't want to make a new instance of Utility, or don't need to you can make the methods in the Utility class static.

```js
 export class Utility {
   static fun1 () { console.log('fn1'); }
   fun2 () { console.log('fn2'); } 
 }
```

And in **other-file.ts** you can write.

```js
import {Utiliy} from "/utility";

Utility.fun1(); // static method invoked with class name

new Utility().fun2(); // non static method needs an instance
```

As for private methods, you can put **access qualifiers** on the methods.

```js
export class Utility {
  private fun1() {
    console.log('fn1');
  }
  fun2() {
    console.log('fn2');
  }
}
```

Then the compiler will not let you call fun1() since it's **private**.

In some cases the privacy is also achieved at run time by the way the code is transpiled to javascript.

Keep in mind, the access qualifiers are for TypeScript only, ES6 has no such things.

Comment: Thank you. it works! (almost)
however when I try to call **private** fun1() from **static** fun2() either by fun1() or this.fun1() it says the **method doesn't exist** (runtime error). How to fix it?

Comment: you can't call non static methods from static methods, only the other way round. Non-static(instance) methods **must** have an instance of the to work on. Static methods have only the Class itself.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, you can use any combination of static and public, private or protected :)